# V4L2 - Header incomplete

Tags: c, linux, gnu, v4l2

I wanted to use V4L with C.

If I follow the tutorial on https://lwn.net/Articles/204545/ and create a file
main.c with the content

```
#include <linux/videodev2.h>
```

This does not compile with `gcc -std=c17`.
It gives the error
`/usr/include/linux/videodev2.h:2320:20: error: field 'timestamp' has incomplete type`

It does work with `gcc -std=gnu11` but I'd rather use c17 instead of a gnu dialect.
Is this something I can expect to work? Should I report a bug? Where would I report a bug.

I do know that I can include `<time.h>` in before `<linux/videodev2.h>` but it still seems buggy.

Edit:
The Issue can be reduced unrelated to v4l but to the linux headers(?).

```
#include <sys/time.h>
struct timespec x;
```

To me it is unclear if `<sys/time.h>` should include `struct timespec` or not.

Comment: Simplest is to file a bug with your distro, and they can forward upstream as needed. But I checked [what seems to be the source](https://git.linuxtv.org/v4l-utils.git/tree/include/linux/videodev2.h), and it does `#include <sys/time.h>`, which [should define `struct timeval`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/systime.h.html), which is what said `timestamp` field is. So it's not clear why you get that problem. Where did you download the library? What version is it?

Comment: This happens accros distros. I have tried archlinux and ubuntu 20.04

Comment: `<sys/time.h>` defined `struct timeval`. But the issue comes from `struct timespec` which is by your source not defined by `<sys/time.h>`

Comment: looking at the source code https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/uapi/linux/videodev2.h#L60 the `<sys/time.h>` is already included in `videodev2.h`

Answer (score 0):

According to `linux/videodev2.h`, `timestamp` is a `struct timeval`. Which in turn is a GNU C library extension.

Comment: Wheredid you find that `timestamp` is a `struct timeval`? From what I can find it is of type `struct timespec` https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/15bc20c6af4ceee97a1f90b43c0e386643c071b4/include/uapi/linux/videodev2.h#L2391

Comment: Look at line 1039.